# Why form destroy event is called more than once?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I never noticed it in my program before, but for one of my TForm I have a destroy event, which frees an object, is called or fired more than once. I don't understand why.

```
procedure THTrendFrm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LogAlarm.Free;  <---Invalid Pointer Operation exception is raised
end;
```

Thanks in advance,

**Update**: Here is the FastMM message window right after my program is shutdown.
TAlarmMsg is the class from which LogAlarm is created.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try my suggestion yet? Call Free on the form object from your .dpr file, after Application.Run.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did apply your suggestion and FastMM still caught the error.

Comment: I just figured out my problem. I just saw Application.CreateForm(THTrendFrm, HTrend) twice in project dpr file. I deleted the duplicate and it is working fine.

Comment: See this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/82AG0_kHonU/ft53lAjxWRMJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Heffernan and others. I found my problem and fixed it. The TForm in question was being created twice in my project file like so.

Application.CreateForm(HTrendFrm, HTrend);

That explains why destroy was called twice.

Once I removed the duplicate line, it is shutting down fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `TForm.OnDestroy` event is not called multiple times, so you have to be freeing the `LogAlarm` object somewhere else in your code before the `OnDestroy` event is triggered.

Comment: I think there is a VCL bug that means forms can be destroyed twice. I work around it by destroying my main form in the .dpr file rather than letting the Application destroy it via Owner mechanism

Comment: Remy, I did put break at this line and stepped through when I shutdown my program. It did break on that line twice. First time, there was no exception or error message. Second time, it raised the exception. LogAlarm object is created and destroyed within the same Unit or pas file. It is not freed no where in my project files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have never encountered such a bug before.

Comment: @digitalanalog: if your breakpoint is being twice, then look at the call stack each time and trace through how the Form could be getting destroyed twice.  It definately should not be under normal conditions.

Comment: Here's my QC report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88776  Not sure if it's the same thing but it sounds plausible

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've created LogAlarm.

If LogAlarm is a TComponent descendant, and you've created it with the form as an owner, you shouldn't call Free on it, because the component will automatically be cleaned up once the form gets destroyed.

Or if you insist on cleaning it up yourself, leave owner as nil during creation.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to Free an object that is owned. Your last sentence is incorrect. Freeing an object removes it from its owner's list of owned objects.

Comment: That's not really what i meant. My point was that you should construct like create(nil) if you don't want an owner to do the cleaning.  When debugging it's probably wiser to first rule out programming errors before assuming that it's a bug in the vcl.

Comment: I slightly rephrased the last sentence

Comment: And it's not exactly safe to blindly call free on an owned object, because you don't know if the owner destroyed it in the meanwhile. Calling freeandnil() is probably a better idea in this case, but let's not start that subject again :)

Comment: The thing about this Q is that the form is being destroyed twice. The error is raised when LogAlarm gets accessed but that's just the first access in the second destruction. The ownership of LogAlarm is neither here nor there. Form's should not be destroyed twice.